# Are there simple way to form cyclic group of huge order using algebraic datatypes?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

To create a cyclic group of order N, in Haskell, you could, for example, define a type for big integers, `data BigInt = B0 BigInt | B1 BigInt | B`, and the usual `add`/`mod` operations. You could then define `op a b = mod (add a b) n` to get an additive group of order `n`. The problem is that the implementation of `add` and `mod` are relatively complex, involving tricky state-passing recursion with carry bits, etc. Is there a more direct, natural way to create cyclic groups using just datatypes? Example:

```
data T = A T T | B T T | C
```

Is it possible to define a relatively simple `add :: T -> T -> T` for that datatype which allows us to define such group? I've been trying some tree-rotation schemes, but seems like it is not easy to generate an operation with a huge period.

Comment: Do you have to define your data type that way? Haskell already has support for arbitrary precision integers with `Integer`, so it would be much simpler to define `newtype BigInt = BigInt Integer`, then define appropriate instances of `Num`, `Integral`, etc for your type. You might want to use a smart constructor `mkBigInt :: Integer -> BigInt` to ensure that a `BigInt` value begins in the range `0 .. n - 1`.

Comment: That is not what I mean, I'm specifically asking if it is possible with datatypes alone. Integer uses FFI under the hoods.

Comment: how are BigInt/T meant to represent elements of your cyclic group?

Comment: All cyclic groups are isomorphic to the integers - so is this just about representing integers without machine integers? What about `(Nat, Nat)` where `(n,m) := n - m` - or even `(Bool, Nat)`. Such definitions aren't very efficient (but neither is any inductive definition of integers, compared to machine integers) but have straightforward arithmethic operations.

Comment: That's not quite right.  The set of all (finite) cyclic groups is isomorphic to the naturals: each group can be represented by the number of elements in the group.  The set of elements/actions of any given cyclic group of size n is the set of size n.